# MAMP 3.2 debug.log keeps on growing on Windows 10

Tags: mamp

I just installed MAMP 3.2 on Windows 10 and I've noticed debug.log in MAMP/logs directory increasing its size every second with this message:

```
14/04/2016 8:48:33:::Error in GetAllFileNamesFromDirectoryWithFileMask.
14/04/2016 8:48:34:::Error in GetAllFileNamesFromDirectoryWithFileMask.
14/04/2016 8:48:35:::Error in GetAllFileNamesFromDirectoryWithFileMask.
14/04/2016 8:48:36:::Error in GetAllFileNamesFromDirectoryWithFileMask.
```

Do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

P.S. This is my first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue is solved on MAMP 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ransomware Protrction (Bitdefender, ...)

Add trusted applications

- ...\mamp\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe
- ...\mamp\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
- ...\mamp\MAMP.exe

restart MAMP

Comment: I am seeing exactly this problem, but am not running Bitdefender. I disabled Kaspersky and checked those two are allowed with Windows Firewall. I am also having problems as soon as I try to define virtual hosts and want to at least eliminate this one as a possible cause

Comment: I only have Windows Defender. I've put these two in the Exclusions List but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @AlbertP. add ...\mamp\MAMP.exe  too.

Comment: @jamesinealing trust mamp\MAMP.exe  too

Comment: @RO'KAISAKKON I've even included the whole MAMP directory. The problem persists.