# Problems getting virtual hosts to work in MAMP on Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, mamp, virtualhost

I have had to give up my old Macbook after moving jobs, and am migrating MAMP to a Windows 10 machine.

All seems to be set up fine, but I am having issues with the virtual hosts finding the files.

The symptoms:

- When I visit any of my virtual hosts, including localhost, the page displays a 404 'The requested URL / was not found on this server.'
- However, http://localhost/MAMP/index.php?language=English and sub pages like phpMyAdmin still work fine.

Troubleshooting:

- a typical entry in httpd-vhost.conf is

      DocumentRoot "F:\GitHub\culturepics"
      ServerName culturepics
- I have checked and there is an index.html/php in each directory
- I am getting the line e.g. 
  16/04/16 2:53:09 PM:::Error in GetAllFileNamesFromDirectoryWithFileMask.
  appear in debug.log with a new line seemingly added every second. I have followed the steps described at [MAMP 3.2 debug.log keeps on growing on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616091/mamp-3-2-debug-log-keeps-on-growing-on-windows-10) in Windows Firewall but these were already allowed. I have Kaspersky Internet Security but have disabled it
- in apache_error.log I'm seeing 'Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.c3po-9db5e23802.localdomain] does not exist
  '

My thoughts:

- file permissions?
- firewall? (noting the above)
- the fact that MAMP is installed on C: and the files are on F: ?
- something really stupid I've missed!

Any steps to how I can further troubleshoot this would be appreciated!

Comment: Just out of interest: if you "have to give up" your MacBook which apparently  was your development environment, then why do you migrate to an MS-Windows based system? Why not instead migrate to a GNU/Linux system which undoubtedly will be _much_ closer to your previous environment, since both are unixoid?

Comment: That's a fair question, but the new work is Windows based and I had my old pre Macbook windows PC here at home. I had hoped it would be an easy transition ;)

Comment: I suggest you disable all but one virtual host and start tackling that one. Especially that error message about the DocumentRoot not existing sounds strange, looking at the path. Where does that come from?

Comment: Thanks @arkascha - I went for the more radical approach of a complete wipe and reinstall, but even just switching to the vhosts conf file with only localhost defined has given the same error. I also tried switching port in MAMP away from 80 to 8010. What this has resulted in is successfully serving the index.html from the default htdocs at localhost:8010 *and* at mydomain:8010  I'm even more confused!